# How to set form location to parent form center?

Tags: c#, winforms

I set my Form's StartPosition to CenterParent. Then I change my Form.ClientSize in Form.Load() event.

Because of this my Form is not centered anymore.

Edit:

I use form.ShowDialog() to show the form.

Comment: If you resize the form then you'll have to re-center it. Simple as that.

Comment: @DanWilson - I believe that "How?" is the question.

Comment: Why do you change the size at first?

Comment: @Reniuz I change the size because I show different content to different users.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` has overload that takes `IWin32Window` as a parameter. You can do:

```
myForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

and now access `Owner.Location` in `myForm.Load()`. Proceed by setting `myForm.Location` to middle of parent form minus half the width and height of `myForm` respectively as follows:

```
Location = new Point(Owner.Location.X + Owner.Width / 2 - ClientSize.Width / 2,
    Owner.Location.Y + Owner.Height / 2 - ClientSize.Height / 2)
```